# 400 Bad Request from CSOM list query

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

I'm attempting to use CSOM against my on-premises SharePoint 2016 server to return the contents of a list using the following code:

```
var context = new ClientContext("https://sharepoint");
context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

On `context.ExecuteQuery()`, I get a 400 Bad Request every time.  When viewing the log for this request, I get the following:

```
Name=Request (POST:https://sharepoint/testing/_vti_bin/sites.asmx:GetUpdatedFormDigestInformation)
SPRequestModule.BeginRequestHandler End
ObjectCachePerRequest Global:True, Enabled:False
Using input cookie name. CookieName: 'FedAuth'.
Medium  SPSite as SystemAccount:
Token is for a windows account.
The audience uri loads a web application matches. AudienceUri: 'https://sharepoint/testing/_vti_bin/sites.asmx', InputWebApplicationId: 'b11522b6-79fa-4263-ae7a-834b932189cb', InputUrlZone: 'Default'.
The absolute uri validation succeeded. AudienceUri: 'https://sharepoint/testing/_vti_bin/sites.asmx'.
SPApplicationAuthenticationModule: Clear outgoing token context from SpThreadContext
SPRequestModule.PostAuthenticateRequestHandler Begin
Looking up SPSite by ID e6ed9222-8ae1-4156-b137-d8a051fc9300 in memory.
Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, 
UserIdentityName=0#.w|pad\valid.user, ClaimsCount=44
Value for isAnonymousAllowed is : False
Value for checkAuthenticationCookie is : True
SPRequestModule.PostAuthenticateRequestHandler End
SPRequestModule.PostAuthorizeRequestHandler Begin
SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler Begin
SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler End
SPRequestModule.AcquireRequestStateHandler
SPRequestModule.PostAcquireRequestStateHandler Begin
SPRequestModule.PostAcquireRequestStateHandler End
SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler Begin
SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler End
SPRequestModule.PostLogRequestHandler Begin
SPRequestModule.PostLogRequestHandler End
SPRequestModule.EndRequestHandler Begin
Looking up SPSite by ID e6ed9222-8ae1-4156-b137-d8a051fc9300 in memory.
SPRequestModule.PreSendRequestHeaders End
Micro Trace Tags: 0 avwhy,0 nasq,0 az4z8,0 avwhz,11 aytib,0 bjkuz,1 a7r51,0 a1n25,0 a9fy7,0 a9fy6,0 bjvyg,0 avwh6,1 az4z8,0 agb9s,0 ajd6k,0 ajd6l,1 avwh7,0 avwh8,0 avwh0,0 avwh1,0 aj1kn,0 avwh2,0 avwh3,0 avwhu,0 avwhv,0 avwia,0 avwib,0 avwic,0 az4z8,0 avwh5
Sending HTTP response 400 for HTTP request POST to https://sharepoint/_vti_bin/sites.asmx
Leaving Monitored Scope: (Request (POST:https://sharepoint/testing/_vti_bin/sites.asmx:GetUpdatedFormDigestInformation)) Execution Time=22.5760536765152; CPU Milliseconds=10; SQL Query Count=0;Parent=None
SPRequestModule.EndRequestHandler End
```

There are also no errors in the Windows Event log.  Can anyone suggest why I may be getting this error or how I find out what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Sharepoint 2016 CSOM doesn't work with .Net Core which is where I was attempting to use it.

Comment: What was your workaround, directly calling the REST API?

Comment: While I'm sure that would be one workaround, I just backed off and created a .net project instead of .net core.

Comment: this solved the problem